# Get details of outlook selected email message message id using Microsoft Graph client in C#

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using Microsoft Graph client to get outlook email details like read email using message id, subject.
But need help to get selected outlook email message message id using graph client in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Graph does not deal with selected messages - that is purely client-side functionality only accessible through the Outlook Object Model: use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection.

You can translate the MAPI entry id (`MailItem.EntryID` property) to a Graph id using [translateExchangeIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint, but I am not sure why you'd want to: Outlook Object Model will let you retrieve any information available through Graph.

You can play with both in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author).